# Layout Validation in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

How do I get the Layout Validation window in Android Studio? It's usually listed under `View > Tool windows`. Is there a solution that helps you see your layouts displayed on different screen sizes in realtime without actually running an emulator or actual device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Android Studio version `4.1.3`, it's still there in

```
View -> Tool Windows -> Layout Validation
```

[image]

If you can't see it,

- go to settings
- search for Layout Validation
- Click on KeyMap
- Double click on Layout Validation
- Add keyboard shortcut

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In order that the **Layout Validation** window appears, you have to open some of your views (activity, fragment,...) xml layout. Then, the window should automatically appear in the upper right corner of the IDE window. See here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector#layout-validation

If it doesn't appear, then it should be listed under *View > Tool Windows*

Comment: Yeah, unless the currently active tab is an .xml layout, Layout Validation won't even appear in the top menu View > Tool Windows!

Answer (score 1):

As of Arctic Fox 2020.3.1, it seems to appear only if you are in the XML layout editor. It doesn't appear to work (yet) for Jetpack Compose previews.